# concourse with vault and auth cert login to vault difference between CONCOURSE_VAULT_CA_CERT and CONCOURSE_VAULT_CA_PATH

Tags: ssl, concourse

I deploy concourse and vault to kubernetes via helm and using `authBackend: "cert"` `vault auth enable cert`

What is the difference between the following two concourse environment vars / configuration:

## Path to a directory of PEMEncoded CA cert files to verify the vault server SSL cert.
concourse.web.vault.caPath: (env var `CONCOURSE_VAULT_CA_PATH`)

and

secrets.vaultCaCert (env var `CONCOURSE_VAULT_CA_CERT`)

aren't they the same thing?? (pointing to the same vault cert?)

Answer (score 0):

as Jamie Klassen explained to me in https://discuss.concourse-ci.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-concourse-vault-ca-cert-and-concourse-vault-ca-path/2301/4

... right there in the comment it explains that concourse.web.vault.caPath should actually be a path to a directory that could potentially contain many trusted certificates (like /etc/ssl/certs).

When it comes to how to trust the vault server’s CA cert in particular, Concourse’s vault API client delegates to hashicorp/go-rootcerts:

https://github.com/concourse/concourse/blob/95fb8f5f24b4059cdc41f8706f7bbf74f1852148/atc/creds/vault/api_client.go#L204-L214

```
    if ac.tlsConfig.CACert != "" || ac.tlsConfig.CACertFile != "" || ac.tlsConfig.CAPath != "" {
        rootConfig := &rootcerts.Config{
            CAFile:        ac.tlsConfig.CACertFile,
            CAPath:        ac.tlsConfig.CAPath,
            CACertificate: []byte(ac.tlsConfig.CACert),
        }

        if err := rootcerts.ConfigureTLS(config, rootConfig); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
```

and doc comment in that library explains the precedence:

https://github.com/hashicorp/go-rootcerts/blob/c8a9a31cbd7675425d28e4e56713d0368a3aeb2c/rootcerts.go#L13-L28

```
// Config determines where LoadCACerts will load certificates from. When CAFile,
// CACertificate and CAPath are blank, this library's functions will either load
// system roots explicitly and return them, or set the CertPool to nil to allow
// Go's standard library to load system certs.
type Config struct {
    // CAFile is a path to a PEM-encoded certificate file or bundle. Takes
    // precedence over CACertificate and CAPath.
    CAFile string

    // CACertificate is a PEM-encoded certificate or bundle. Takes precedence
    // over CAPath.
    CACertificate []byte

    // CAPath is a path to a directory populated with PEM-encoded certificates.
    CAPath string
}
```

What this means for your helm chart case is that when concourse.web.vault.useCaCert is true, secrets.vaultCaCert will override concourse.web.vault.caPath. Maybe an explanatory comment in the helm chart, would help, or better we could improve the CLI helptext:

https://github.com/concourse/concourse/blob/95fb8f5f24b4059cdc41f8706f7bbf74f1852148/atc/creds/vault/manager.go#L36-L37

```
    CACertFile string `long:"ca-cert"              description:"Path to a PEM-encoded CA cert file to use to verify the vault server SSL cert."`
    CAPath     string `long:"ca-path"              description:"Path to a directory of PEM-encoded CA cert files to verify the vault server SSL cert."`
```